# Webpage button will not respond to getElementById

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, getelementbyid

I have tried many different ways but cannot get a button to respond on a webpage from VBA.
Code I am trying:

```
Set btn = IE.document.getElementById("gs-address-go")
btn.FireEvent ("onmousedown")
btn.FireEvent ("onclick")
btn.Focus
btn.Click
```

HTML extract of the object:

```
<button id="gs-address-go" class="b-btn bold go-btn" onclick="$('#splash-get-walkscore-form').submit(); return false;" aria-label="Go"><span class="icon big-search"></span></button>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: There shouldn't be any space between your function call and its arguments. `btn.FireEvent("onmousedown")` and **not** `btn.FireEvent ("onmousedown")`

Comment: have you tried `btn.form.submit` this `walkscore-form').submit(); ` makes me think its a form submission button.

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Is there any error and which line throw the error? Can the button submit the form in IE without VBA? I tried your code and it worked. You could refer to the simple sample below:</del>

**VBA code:**

```
Sub LOADIE()
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.walkscore.com/score/1730-blake-st-denver-co-80202"
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4
       DoEvents
    Loop

    Set searchbar = IE.document.getElementById("addrbar-street")
    searchbar.Value = "B30 3LT"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))        'add a wait here  
    Set btn = IE.document.getElementById("gs-address-go")
    btn.FireEvent ("onmousedown")
    btn.FireEvent ("onclick")
    btn.Focus
    btn.Click

    'IE.Quit
    'Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Besides, you could also try `btn.FireEvent "onmousedown"` and `btn.FireEvent "onclick"`.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that I can simply use https://www.walkscore.com/score/B30 3LT with the B30 3LT being the search criteria. None of the above seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. I tried with the website you provided and I found that we can add a wait before the button click, then the click function can work. You could check my updated answer.